# Cant ping Google from my macbook air

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, macbook

Safari wasn't connecting to any web pages. So I opened terminal and tried to ping Google and it didn't respond to the ping request

```
PING www.l.Google.com (209.85.143.99): 56 data bytes
```

No response at all after the above line.

I reset the airport. Reset the network. Restarted the laptop.

None of the above has helped.

My other Macbook works perfect. Can ping and access websites.

Anybody able to advise me what to do next please?

Comment: Can you ping the airport from you Macbook Air? What about the other machines on your network? If its plugged in wired to the network does it work?

Comment: Its a Macbook Air.  It has no wired network (unless you have a USB Ethernet adapter)

Comment: Its not a DNS problem, that it resolved out to an IP Address rules that out, or at the very least makes it extremely unlikely.

That leaves a network layer problem somewhere else. Are you using DHCP or have you set anything statically in your network preferences?

Are you sure you're connecting to the correct wireless network?

Comment: Lots of missing information. Are you using a wireless router? Is it configured for DHCP? Is your MBA configured for DHCP? What is your MBA's IP address (do an ifconfig in terminal)?